# Does any C standard header include ASCII aliases?

Tags: c

Would help to avoid doing things like,

```
#define ESC (27)
#define DEL (127)
```

Edit: Looking for either a C standard header or a POSIX C header with this.

Comment: The parentheses are redundant

Comment: those names are way too short to appear in any standard header,

Comment: to avoid 'text replacement' errors,  The parens are often mandatory.  Best to be in the habit of always include the parens

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no. C is described abstractly in terms of *execution character set* and *implementation  character set*, both of which may vary. The characters it uses are not the complete set offered by ASCII. In fact the version of ascii current at the time of the first C compilers didn't even have `'@'` yet.

Searching for "posix character set" turned this up. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap06.html